# How to create a histogram where the number of each data point is already known

Tags: python

I want to know how to create a histogram where the number of each data point is already known. For example, I want to create a histogram on age distribution except I already know the number of people who are that age. I cannot figure out how to plot this correctly. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

As the simplest approach, [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot(age, number_of_people_that_age)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) will give a [frequency polygon](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/frequency-polygon), which is a histogram-like plot.

To plot a proper histogram, you should draw bars with [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

Comment: I think it's the _data_ you're plotting that matters. If you have the binned ages and the numbers of people that fall into each bin, then you have all the data for the histogram. With this data, the histogram is the bar plot with the horizontal axis representing the ages, sorted in increasing order, and the vertical axis - the corresponding counts.

Comment: Can I show you my code so you can review it?

Comment: @JohnSmith, code review is done on [codereview.se]